# How to trigger ajax when API Response is not empty?

Tags: php, ajax, shopify, shopify-app

I'm using Shopify customers/create webhook and getting API response using

```
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($info, true);
```

I want to trigger ajax when $data is not empty

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: {
        'first_name'    : FirstName,
        'last_name'     : LastName,
        'email'         : Email,
        'password'      : Password,
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log("test");                      
    }
});
```

But it only shows the value when I check response in the ngrok inspect, How to make this ajax trigger as the response come please help the file extension is .php because I have created the private app 
Getting response with values [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNAP1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add if condition and run ajax call on ready state, I assume you have already loaded jQuery in your project. Moreover, you are not handling error call backs with ajax function, I have added it along your function.

```
<?php
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($info, true);

 if(!empty($data)){?>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {

      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "insert.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {
        first_name    : FirstName,
        last_name     : LastName,
        email         : Email,
        password      : Password,
       },
       success: function(res) {
          console.log("success");                      
        },
       error: function(res){
            console.log("error"); 
       }
     });// end of ajax

    });// end of ready
 </script>


 <?php
 }// end of if
 ?>
```

You should change dataType given in parameter of ajax function, If your response in server file is JSON then use dataType: "json" But if you are returning HTML from server file then use dataType : "html". Make sure to check the path of ajax file, give full accessible path of file in url parameter.

Comment: Not working it always returns the value in the script when I view the response but ajax is not executing

Comment: Please make sure to define dataType and cross verify the url and ajax request and response parameters inside browser inspect then network tab.

Comment: When I send the test notification from Shopify store it shows the response in ngrok inspect, I am getting the response with ajax script

Comment: var firstName       = 'Bob';
 var lastName        = 'Biller';
 var email           = 'bob@biller.com';
 var password        = '123456789';

Comment: the thing is that I can not load this ajax in document ready or click because I want this ajax to work as respons ereturn something, when I add condition inside the echo other not empty then it shows in the response

Comment: @jhayden Put this ajax call inside a js function, then call created function inside response along required parameters.

Comment: Then you should change your approach to accomplish this task, on your webhook response if you are using same serve then call function directly or use curl to send data to same/other server.

Comment: Alright, kindly help how this can be done using curl

Comment: I'm new in development but I want it to work with ajax only